# VI mode in freetalk

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, readline

I somehow managed to get my [freetalk](http://www.gnu.org/software/freetalk/) into vi-mode. I'm just unsure how I did it (if I restart freetalk I get an emacs-mode).

Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the freetalk documentation, it uses GNU Readline for its line editing features.

According to the [GNU Readline documentation](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC22):

> In order to switch interactively
>   between emacs and vi editing modes,
>   use the command M-C-j (bound to
>   emacs-editing-mode when in vi mode and
>   to vi-editing-mode in emacs mode). The
>   Readline default is emacs mode.

Perhaps you have accidentally hit this keyboard shortcut: M-C-j.  For those not familiar with the notation, this usually refers to <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd>.  Pressing this key combination again should return you to emacs mode.